# SQLITE date formate

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently working on a project that utilizes SQLite. I need to covert a stored date format from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `YYYY/MM/DD`. However, I don't know how to convert in SQLite.

Comment: Using substr(<input>,7,4) + '/' +substr<input>, 1,2) + '/' +substr(<input>,4,2)?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look here:

https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

What you need is **strftime** function to specify the format.

Comment: The input is not one of `strftime()`'s [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).